# Saving list in django database

Tags: python, django

I have a question about saving a list in Django database. Let me explain my problem, is pretty complex so I hope you understand that.
At the base, I have a list of values (called learning objectives) where each student will have a grade from 1 to 5.
Now, the idea is that the teacher, to give the evaluation, will press a checkbox corresponding to each grade and the database will create some sort of record to store the student's evaluation.

models.py

```
GRADING_VALUE = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5'),
)


class Grading(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GRADING_VALUE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class LearningObjective(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    grading = models.ForeignKey(
        Grading, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey(
        Note, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MissionEntry(models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    log_entry = models.ForeignKey(LogEntry, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mission) + ' ' + str(self.log_entry)


class LearningObjGradingNote(models.Model):
    learning_objective = models.ForeignKey(
        LearningObjective, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    grade = models.ForeignKey(
        Grading, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey(
        Note, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def mission_test(request, pk):
    mission = Mission.objects.get(id=pk)
    learning_obj = LearningObjective.objects.filter(mission_id=mission)
    grading = Grading.objects.all()
    aircrafts = Aircraft.objects.all()
    aerodromes = Aerodrome.objects.all()
    function_type = FunctionType.objects.all()
    students = Student.objects.all()
    instructors = Instructor.objects.all()
    context = {
        'mission': mission,
        'learning_obj': learning_obj,
        'grading': grading,
        'aircrafts': aircrafts,
        'aerodromes': aerodromes,
        'function_type': function_type,
        'students': students,
        'instructors': instructors
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aircraft = request.POST.get('aircraft')
        adep = request.POST.get('adep')
        ades = request.POST.get('ades')
        date = request.POST.get('date')
        etd = request.POST.get('etd')
        ata = request.POST.get('ata')
        function_type_obj = request.POST.get('function_type')
        student = request.POST.get('student')
        instructor = request.POST.get('instructor')
        note = request.POST.get('note')
        comment = request.POST.getlist('comment')
        grade = request.POST.getlist('grade')

        comment_list = []
        for com in comment:
            comment_list.append(com)
        print(comment_list)

        grade_list = []
        for g in grade:
            grade_list.append(g)
        print(grade_list)
        lo_list = []
        for lo in learning_obj:
            lo_list.append(lo)
        print(lo_list)

        try:
            log_entry = LogEntry.objects.create(aircraft_id=aircraft, adep_id=adep, ades_id=ades, date=date, etd=etd,
                                                ata=ata, function_type_id=function_type_obj, student_id=student, instructor_id=instructor, note=note)
            print(log_entry)

            learning_objective = LearningObjective(
                grading_id=grade_list, note_id=comment_list, learning_objective=learning_obj)
            learning_objective.save()

            mission_entry = MissionEntry.objects.create(
                log_entry_id=log_entry, mission_id=mission)
            learning_obj.save()
            log_entry.save()
            mission_entry.save()

            messages.success(request, "Successfully Added New Flight")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mission:mission_test', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Add New Flight")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mission:mission_test', kwargs={'pk': pk}))

    return render(request, 'mission/mission_test.html', context)
```

Now, the part where I am having problem (let alone I know there are other things to be fixed, but I am on it) is in saving the list of grading and comments (which can be also empty) for each learning objective. How can I do that with a for loop?
I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: maybe i'm not getting your problem fully but still from whatever i get. why don't you save the data in a json format in database.

Comment: Ok, that’s something I actually didn't think about. I pretty new to programming. How can I achieve that? I mean, should I return a JsonResponse?

Comment: can you please explain me a bit about your problem. I think i misunderstood it.

Comment: I have a template called Mission, where I have multiple Learning Objectives on it. Each learning objective shall have an evaluation from 1 to 5 and an optional comment. I created a model for the Mission, a model for the Learning Objective, a model for the Comment (called Note) and a model for the Grade. The issue is that, when I wanna save the grades and the comments, they're in a List, which I don't understand how to save and "connect" to the Learning Objective.

Comment: ok i got your point . you can create json object of each dataset in javascript like this eg: ```[{'mission': "value" , 'object': 'value' , 'comment': "value"}, {'mission': "value" , 'object': 'value' , 'comment': "value"}]``` . then using ajax call you can send this data to view.py and there you will get the data in a way you could extract value from . Below i'm posting my code for your reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

`form.html`

```
    {% for row in locality %}
    <div class='locality_field locality_style'>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8 custom_TopmMar">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locality_name" id="exist_locality_{{ row.Locality_Id }}" data-localityId='{{ row.Locality_Id }}' value='{{ row.Locality_Name }}'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 custom_TopmMar">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" {% if not row.locality_count %} class="border_btn red_btn_bg red_border btn_del_locality" data-localityId="{{ row.Locality_Id }}" {% else %} class="border_btn red_btn_bg red_border disabled" title="There are Stores associated to this locality, so it cannot be deleted"{% endif %}><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div> 
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

`script.js`

```
-------------this is what you have to do --------------------
    let locality_list = []
    let locality_names = $('input[name="locality_name"]');
    for (const locality of locality_names) {
      locality_list.push({
        locality_id: $(locality).data("localityid"),
        locality_name: $(locality).val(),
      });
    }

$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: `/a/md/s_lo/${$("#city_id").val()}`,
        type: "post",
        // beforeSend: function () {
        //   $("#cover-spin").fadeIn();
        // },
        data: {
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: $(
            '#edit_city_locality_form input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]'
          ).val(),
          city_id: $("#city_id").val(),
          city_name: $("#city_name").val(),
          locality_list: JSON.stringify(locality_list),
        },
        success: function (response) {
          if (response) {
            location.reload();
          }
        },
      });
-------------this is what you have to do --------------------
```

`views.py`

```
def save_locality(request):
    '''
    saving locality data
    '''
    try:
        locality_list = request.POST.get('locality_list')
        city_name = request.POST.get("city_name")
        city_id = request.POST.get("city_id")
        
        return data

    except Exception as e:
```

**I'm not posting whole code here. Only the code you need for reference**
Please like it, if this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! I still didn't solve completely, but that's on me because I have almost 0 experience in ajax, so I need to study more and will try to fix the issue!! Thank you very much for your help